# How to accommodate timing variability in writing to tcp socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, winsock2

As a test, I'm writing a series of byte arrays to a tcp socket from an Android application, and reading them in a C++ application.

**Java**

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.2");                          
Socket socket = new Socket(address, 1300);                   
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())
```

...

```
if(count == 0) {
    out.write(first, 0, first.length);
} else if(count == 1) {
    out.write(second, 0, second.length);
}
```

**C++**

```
do {
    iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, 3, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << (int)(signed char)recvbuf[i] << std::endl;
    }
} while (iResult > 0);
```

As it stands, on the first receipt, recv[2] = -52, which I assume to be a junk value, as the output stream has not yet written the second byte array by the time I've received the first segment.

However, when I pause after the the ListenSocket has accepted the connection:

```
ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
std::cin.ignore();
```

...giving the sender time to do both writes to the stream, recv[2] = 3, which is the first value of the second written byte array.

If I ultimately want to send and receive a constant stream of discrete arrays, how can I determine after I've received the last value of one array, whether the next value in the buffer is the first value of the next array or whether it's a junk value?

I've considered that udp is more suitable for sending a series of discrete data sets, but I need the reliability of tcp. I imagine that tcp is used in this way regularly, but it's not clear to me how to mitigate this issue.

**EDIT:**
In the actual application for which I'm writing this test, I do implement length prefixing.  I don't think that's relevant though; even if I know I'm at the end of a data set, I need to know whether the next value on the buffer is junk or the beginning of the next set.

Comment: You can't make TCP do that. TCP treats all your data as a single stream of bytes. You should send how big the array is, and on the receiver read how big the array is, then read that much stuff.

Comment: Semi off topic: In `iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, 3, 0);` `iResult` is the number of bytes read, if any, or a negative value on error. So after checking for and handling the negative case, the `for` loop printing the results should look something like: `for (int i = 0; i < iResult; i++)` to handle the case where you read data but didn't get three bytes.

Comment: @immibis Do you mean to say that TCP cannot and is not used in this way?  I must use udp?

Comment: @Jayz7522 No, I'm saying if you send data in blocks, you will not receive it in blocks. You have to invent your own blocks if you want blocks.

Comment: @user4581301 That wasn't off topic at all.  That was exactly the information I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: The final ***flags*** parameter to [recv](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv)  can be passed `MSG_WAITALL`, in which case it will block and ensure either the hoped-for 3 bytes are read before `recv` returns, or it will report an error/disconnect.  That may simplify your code, as long as you can trust the Java side not to have crashed before sending the 3 bytes.  More generally, you may not want to hard-coded `3` in the server and client, so may initially send a fixed-length binary-encoded message length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```

The problem is here. It should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < iResult; i++)
```

You're printing out data that you may not have received. This is the explanation of the 'junk value'.

You can't assume that `recv()` fills the buffer.

You must also check `iResult` for both -1 and zero before this loop, and take the appropriate actions, which are different in each case.

Comment: Looks like I wasn't as off topic as I thought.

Comment: Yes, I made bad assumptions about what recv() returns.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you point out, TCP is stream-based, so there's no built-in way to say "here's a specific chunk of data".  What you want to do is add your own "message framing".  A simple way to do that is called "length prefixing".  Where you first send the size of the data packet, and then the packet itself.  Then the receiver will know when they've gotten all the data.

**Sending side**

1. send length of packet (as a known size -- say a 32-bit int)
2. send packet data

**Receiving side**

1. read length of packet
2. read that many bytes of data
3. process fully-received packet

Check out this article for more information: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented a length prefix in my actual application (though, I'll check out the article to see if it needs improvement); however I don't think that addresses this issue.  Just because I know that I'm at the end of one chunk, doesn't mean I know whether the next byte is the beginning of the next chunk or whether it's junk. Right?

Comment: @Jayz7522 You will not receive any junk.

Comment: @Jayz7522 I think the "junk" you are seeing is you printing out uninitialized memory.

Comment: @Jayz7522: the crucial insight is that with the length prefixing advocated in this answer, at each stage you know how much data you *hope* to read: first four bytes, then however many bytes the four-byte number indicated.  For each of those, you either loop calling `recv` until you've assembled that number of bytes, or you use `MSG_WAITALL` as explained in my comment under your question.